# Question about locally free sheaf in terms of stalk (Hartshorne exercise)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, sheaf-theory, schemes

This is my attempt to solve Hartshorne exercise 5.7 section II.

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf. I want to prove the following:

> If $\mathcal{F}_x$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module for some $x\in X$ then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\mathcal{F}_{|U}$ is free

**My attempt**

Let $x_0$ be the point of $X$ in which $\mathcal{F}$ has free stalk.  Since $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent then  it is of finite type, so let $s_1,\dots,s_n\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ be local sections in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ such that $s_{1,x_0},\dots,s_{n,x_0}$ generate $\mathcal{F}_{x_0}\cong\mathcal{O}^n_{X,x_0}$. One can easily show that $s_{1,x},\dots,s_{n,x}$ generate $\mathcal{F}_{x}$ for all $x\in V\subset U$. In particular we obtain a surjective morphism \begin{equation*}\phi:\mathcal{O}^n_{|V}\to\mathcal{F}_{|V}
\end{equation*}
But $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent so the kernel of such morphism is finitely generated and it is zero over $x_0$ ( I mean the stalk of the sheaf kernel is zero at $x_0$). In particular the induced map $\phi_{x_0}$ on the stalk is an isomorphism. So by some lemmata on stack exchange it follows that $\phi$ is injective when restricted to some $W\subset V$ neighbourhood of $x_0$ and in particular it gives an isomorphism between $\mathcal{O}^n_{|W}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{|W}$.

Now, I have two questions:

**1) Does my argument work?**

**2) Where did I use the noetherian hypothesis on $X$? Am I missing something?**

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "some lemmata on stack exchange". the actual reason is that the kernel is again coherent because it is a subsheaf of $O^n$ and X is notherian(this is where you use notherian hypothesis) then because stalk of this coherent sheaf is zero at $x$ it should be zero on a neighborhood of $x$(this is an easy exercise in algebra)

Comment: the rest of your argument is fine

Comment: @ali I mean exactly what you wrote in your comment. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Why the Noetherian hypothesis: Hartshorne only defines coherent sheaves on Noetherian schemes, because in the general case they do not behave well (at least with the same definition). You can read about a more general definition of coherent sheaves in Ravi Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry.